How to replicate this curly brace
I'm a novice when it comes to TeX. Does anyone know how to get the exact curly brace in the pic? I've searched everywhere and found nothing. I just like how it looks, nothing more. ;-) Thanks in advance.


This question is similar to: How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can find it in the calligraphy library of the tikz package The calligraphy Package

Welcome. // I suggest having a look at the manuals of the packages mentioned, at least at amsmath. Find it e.g. via your search engine: ctan amsmath

You are not just looking for \begin{cases} ... \end{cases}?

@md2perpe Not at all. I'm more interested in how the braces look. It may not seem that important to someone else, but it does to me. I've seen that kinda curly brace in a couple of books published by Springer, and have always wanted to know how I can reproduce it. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Differences I see between this and cases/dcases/\left\{: (1) the top and bottom is more curved and comes to a sharper point and (2) it's thicker at the middle point (\left\{ looks almost as thick, the other two are definitely thinner).

@Teepeemm Finally, someone recognises the difference.

The text and math fonts employed in the OP's screenshot are some clones of Times Roman (or possibly Times New Roman). A free-of-charge way of employing these fonts in one's document is to load the newtx package -- which, in turn, loads the newtxtext and newtxmath packages.
There's nothing special to the tall curly opening brace. In a LaTeX document, it can generated (in math mode) via
\left\{ ... \right.

where \right. is simply the empty counterpart to \left\{ and ... could be a three-row aligned environment.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' environment
\usepackage{newtx}   % Times Roman text and math fonts
\counterwithin{equation}{section} % just for this example
\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{4}   % just for this example
\setcounter{equation}{15}

\noindent
Show that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{H_k^{(m)}}{n-k}=
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}, \quad m=1; \\
&\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{H_i}{i^{2r-1}} + \dotsb, \quad m=2r-1\dots; \\
&\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{H_i}{i^{2r}} + \dotsb, \quad m=2r\ge 2,
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}
where $H_n^{(m)}=1+\frac{1}{2^m}+\dots+\frac{1}{n^m}$, $m\ge 1$, is the \dots

\end{document}


Thanks for your response. The curly braces are not the same though.

@KaraboDibakoane They look the same to me.  Could you be a little more specific about what's different?  "not the same" and "take a closer look" aren't all that helpful.

@Teepeemm My apologies. What's different about them is their "thickness" and "curvature" at the opposite ends. I'm not sure if I'm making any sense.

@KaraboDibakoane - Please edit your posting to show a close-up screenshot of just the curly brace you're interested in reproducing. The currently available screenshot just doesn't provide enough visual detail.

@Mico I see. I'll do as you suggested. Thanks.

The math font is MathTime Professional II (mtpro2)—a commercial math font which can be downloaded from https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html.
Here is a minimal code example reproducing part of the screenshot above:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mtpro2}
\begin{document}

\[\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{H_k^{(m)}}{n-k} = 
\begin{cases}
  H_n^2 - H_n^{(2)} \\
  \displaystyle\sum_i^n \frac{H_i}{i^{2r-1}} \\
  \displaystyle\sum_i^n \frac{H_i}{i^{2r}}
\end{cases}\]

\end{document}


Using mtpro2's \ccases contruction
\[\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{H_k^{(m)}}{n-k} = 
\ccases{
  H_n^2 - H_n^{(2)} \\
  \displaystyle\sum_i^n \frac{H_i}{i^{2r-1}} \\
  \displaystyle\sum_i^n \frac{H_i}{i^{2r}}
}\]


Using mathtools and its dcases
\[\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{H_k^{(m)}}{n-k} = 
\begin{dcases}
  H_n^2 - H_n^{(2)} \\
  \displaystyle\sum_i^n \frac{H_i}{i^{2r-1}} \\
  \displaystyle\sum_i^n \frac{H_i}{i^{2r}}
\end{dcases}\]



+1 . The spacing between the rows of a cases environment is quite tight. For the material at hand, loading the mathtools package (a superset of the amsmath package) and employing its dcases environmentmight be preferable to using a cases environment. A separate thought: If one happens to have the MathTime II Professional fonts -- which I do, incidentally -- it may be a nice idea to use its \ccases{...} command instead of \left\{ ... \right. to obtain a truly elegant curly brace.

@Mico Thanks. I've added.

@Stephen I agree. The math font is mtpro2. However, the curly braces are not identical. Take a closer look.
